# What events can I attach to jQuery's on() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Besides click, mouseover, and mouseleave, are there any other events for jQuery's on() function or are those the main uses for on()? I can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: It's not a jQuery thing (for the most part) - it's a JavaScript thing. `input`, `change`, `focus`, `blur`, `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `touchstart`, `keydown`, `keyup`, ...

Comment: There are many more. Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use built-in DOM events or you can create your own events.  Here's a list of some of the built-in DOM events (all events don't occur on all types of objects):

- click
- dblclick
- mousedown
- mouseup
- mouseover
- mousemove
- mouseout
- keydown
- keyup
- keypress
- load
- unload
- abort
- error
- resize
- scroll
- select
- change
- submit
- reset
- focus
- blur
- focusin
- focusout
- touchstart
- touchend
- touchmove
- touchenter
- touchleave
- touchcancel
- cut
- copy
- paste
- beforecut
- beforecopy
- beforepaste
- contextmenu
- drag
- dragstart
- dragenter
- dragover
- dragleave
- dragend
- drop
- selectstart
- beforeunload
- readystatechange
- beforeprint
- afterprint

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events for a decent description of most of these.

Comment: You can create your own events as well.

Answer (score 1):

on() can be used for anything. It is just a way to delegate events to a specific DOM element.

Check out: http://api.jquery.com/on/
It will tell you how to "convert" bind, live, delegate functions into the new "on" method.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Parris [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12207223/1637178) you can do

```
$("#whatever").on("my.awesome_event", function(event, one, two, three){
    // stuff ...
});

$("#whatever").trigger("my.awesome_event", [1,2,3]);
```

In this example variables `one, two, three` will have values `1, 2, 3`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use any built in events (change, focus, mousedown, blur, touchstart, etc...) or you can make your own events and bind them even!

Answer (score 0):

I use jQuery's on for both built-in DOM events such as change, click, blur, etc. and my own custom events within classes.  For most classes I want custom events for, I will do this:

```
this.events = $({});
```

I can then bind custom events like this:

```
foo.events.on("myCustomEvent", function(e) {
     // Do something
});
```

And I can trigger like this:

```
this.events.triggerHandler("myCustomEvent");
```